# Angular 5 Promise returns undefined

Tags: angular, angular-http

I'm trying to return a promise after an HTTP Request but I get undefined when I print the return on my component.

service:

```
getPlace() {
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/place/')
      .toPromise()
      .then(
          res => { // Success
            this.results = res.results.map(item => {
              var place = new Place();
              place.place_id = item.place_id;
              place.name=item.name;
              place.vicinity=item.vicinity;
              place.coordinates = new Coordinates();
              place.coordinates.latitude = item.geometry.location.lat;
              place.coordinates.longitude = item.geometry.location.lng;
              return place;
            });

            resolve();
            console.log(  this.results);
          },
          msg => { // Error
            reject(msg);
          }
      );
});
return promise;
}
```

here its my component call:

```
getPlace(): void{
 this.cityService.getPlace().then( (res) => {console.log(res);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument function in `.then()` will get as argument whatever you pass to  `resolve()`.

So when you do `resolve('stuff')` then an eventual `.then(r => console.log(r))` would print `'stuff'`.

You are getting `undefined` because right now your `resolve` is being called without arguments:

```js
      res => { // Success
        this.results = res.results.map(item => {
          var place = new Place();
          place.place_id = item.place_id;
          place.name=item.name;
          place.vicinity=item.vicinity;
          place.coordinates = new Coordinates();
          place.coordinates.latitude = item.geometry.location.lat;
          place.coordinates.longitude = item.geometry.location.lng;
          return place;
        });

        resolve();                              // <==== resolve without arguments here
        console.log(  this.results);
      },
```

Since you want the `.then()` to get the `results`, add it to the `resolve`. The code above then should be:

```js
      res => { // Success
        this.results = res.results.map(item => {
          var place = new Place();
          place.place_id = item.place_id;
          place.name=item.name;
          place.vicinity=item.vicinity;
          place.coordinates = new Coordinates();
          place.coordinates.latitude = item.geometry.location.lat;
          place.coordinates.longitude = item.geometry.location.lng;
          return place;
        });

        resolve(this.results);                  // <===== changed this line
        console.log(  this.results);
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning undefined, because you're not using the Promise resolution.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/place/')
      .toPromise()
      .then(
          res => { // Success
            this.results = res.results.map(item => {
              var place = new Place();
              place.place_id = item.place_id;
              place.name=item.name;
              place.vicinity=item.vicinity;
              place.coordinates = new Coordinates();
              place.coordinates.latitude = item.geometry.location.lat;
              place.coordinates.longitude = item.geometry.location.lng;
              //return place; Remove this
            });

        resolve(this.results);
        console.log(  this.results);
      },
      msg => { // Error
        reject(msg);
      }
  );
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem, but since I want to return the entire array it must be resovlve(  this.results);

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you wanted to just return 'place.' I will update my answer so it doesn't misguide anyone that may read it later.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using the promise correctly, apparently the issue was because of HTTP interceptor I had to handle some error status code.

I was using

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    catchError((err: any) => {
        // ...

        return of(err);
    })
);
```

Changed to

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    catchError((err: any) => {
        // ...

        return throwError(err);
    })
);
```